# How do I restrict which properties are bound using aspnetcore JSON from body of request

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-1.0

I could using `[Bind("properties to include")]` on an MVC action in ASPNET MVC 4. How do I restrict binding to specific properties using AspNetCore/MVC6? (RC2)

Answer (score 0):

You could use JSON.NET's `JsonIgnoreAttribute` on properties which you want to exclude from deserialization, but note that this also makes the property not to serialize also. (Ideally you should have a model which is exactly what you expect from the user instead of ignoring certain properties, but I am not aware of how  your requirements are)

Comment: I wanted to use the same model for create, update, and index actions. I do not need certain properties bound for each one, but would need all of them for index method. The `Bind` attribute would have saved me from defining three separate classes, which is what I ended up doing.